# Google ARCore Sceneform How to detect ray hit to ar object

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arcore, sceneform

I am new to Google AR core and Sceneform. I want to develop a basic fps game on Android Studio, when user touches anywhere on the screen AR object will be created and if button is pushed, a ray will be shot from the center of the screen and if the ray hits to any created AR object, the score will increase.
The code is below, but i cannot continue more. How can i do?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final double MIN_OPENGL_VERSION = 3.0;

    private ArFragment arFragment;
    private ModelRenderable mRenderable;
    private ImageButton imageButton;
    private TextView scoreText;
    private int score=0;
    private Set<Vector3> position = new HashSet<Vector3>();


   // Set<Vector3> obj_set = new HashSet<Vector3>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (!checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(this)) {
            return;
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreText);


        setUpModel();
        setUpPlane();

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Camera camera = arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().getCamera();
                    Ray ray = new Ray(camera.getWorldPosition(),camera.getForward());

                    HitTestResult result = arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().hitTest(ray);
                    if (result.getNode() != null && result.getDistance() < 0) {
                        // Hit something
                        //doSomething(result.getNode());
                        Log.e(TAG,"RAYCASTING ERROR");
                    }else{
                        Iterator value = position.iterator();
                        while(value.hasNext()){
                            if(position.equals(result.getPoint())){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"HIT WAS DETECTED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                score = score + 5;
                                scoreText.setText("SCORE: " + score + "");
                                Log.e(TAG,"HEY THERE");
                            }
                            else{
                                Log.e(TAG,"NOOOOOOO");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR ON BUTTON");
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void setUpModel() { //Load the model
        WeakReference<MainActivity> weakActivity = new WeakReference<>(this);

        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this, R.raw.model)
                .setIsFilamentGltf(true)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> {
                    MainActivity activity = weakActivity.get();
                    if (activity != null) {
                        mRenderable = modelRenderable;
                    }
                })
                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Model can not be loaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return null;
                });
    }

    private void setUpPlane() {//Attach the scene to the node
        arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(new BaseArFragment.OnTapArPlaneListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTapPlane(HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                // Creates the anchor
                Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
                AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
                anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
                createModel(anchorNode);
            }
        });
    }
    private void createModel(AnchorNode anchorNode) {// Create the transformable model and add it to the anchor
        TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        node.setParent(anchorNode);
        node.setRenderable(mRenderable);
        node.select();

        position.add(anchorNode.getWorldPosition());

    }

    public static boolean checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(final Activity activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires Android N or later");
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Sceneform requires Android N or later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activity.finish();
            return false;
        }
        String openGlVersionString =
                ((ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                        .getDeviceConfigurationInfo()
                        .getGlEsVersion();
        if (Double.parseDouble(openGlVersionString) < MIN_OPENGL_VERSION) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 later");
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 or later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            activity.finish();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understood what you want to achieve but if you want to increase score when user points towards the object and presses button then you could check just that the result != null and then do your action, why do you have the hit detection logic in the else part? So you could have:

```
...
    HitTestResult result = arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().hitTest(ray);
    if (result.getNode() != null) {
        // Hit something
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"HIT WAS DETECTED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         score = score + 5;
         scoreText.setText("SCORE: " + score + "");                  
    }
...
```

This will of course keep the score increasing as long as the user points towards the object.